# Run Javascript on first page load only

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want this code to work only on the first time the page load.

Is there anyway to use not `IsPostBack` on javascript?

`IsPostBack` :Gets a value that indicates whether the page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback. [More here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx/).

```
<script>  

window.onload = function TimedCss()
{

    setTimeout(myTimeout1, 0500) 
    setTimeout(myTimeout2, 1000) 
    setTimeout(myTimeout3, 1500)
    setTimeout(myTimeout4, 2000) 
    setTimeout(myTimeout5, 2500)
    setTimeout(myTimeout6, 3000)
}



}
function myTimeout1() 
{
    document.getElementById("LBLName").className = " animated fadeInLeft";
    document.getElementById("LBLName").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function myTimeout2() 
{ 
    document.getElementById("LBLDescription").className = " animated rotateIn";
    document.getElementById("LBLDescription").style.visibility = "visible"; 
}
function myTimeout3() 
{
    document.getElementById("P1").className = " animated zoomIn";
    document.getElementById("P1").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function myTimeout4()
{
    document.getElementById("TXTQuantity").className = " animated flipInY";
    document.getElementById("TXTQuantity").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function myTimeout5()
{
    document.getElementById("LBLPrice").className = " animated slideInLeft";
    document.getElementById("LBLPrice").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function myTimeout6()
{
    document.getElementById("BTNAddToCart").className += " animated fadeInUp";
    document.getElementById("BTNAddToCart").style.visibility = "visible";
}

</script>
```

## **Edit - Solution:**

```
<script>
window.onload = function TimedCSS()
{
    var isPostBack=<%= IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>

    if (!isPostBack)
    {
        setTimeout(myTimeout1, 0500) 
        setTimeout(myTimeout2, 1000) 
        setTimeout(myTimeout3, 1500)
        setTimeout(myTimeout4, 2000) 
        setTimeout(myTimeout5, 2500)
        setTimeout(myTimeout6, 3000)
    }




function myTimeout1() 
{
    document.getElementById("LBLName").className = " animated fadeInLeft";
    document.getElementById("LBLName").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function myTimeout2() 
{ 
    document.getElementById("LBLDescription").className = " animated rotateIn";
    document.getElementById("LBLDescription").style.visibility = "visible"; 
}
function myTimeout3() 
{
    document.getElementById("P1").className = " animated zoomIn";
    document.getElementById("P1").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function myTimeout4()
{
    document.getElementById("TXTQuantity").className = " animated flipInY";
    document.getElementById("TXTQuantity").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function myTimeout5()
{
    document.getElementById("LBLPrice").className = " animated slideInLeft";
    document.getElementById("LBLPrice").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function myTimeout6()
{
    document.getElementById("BTNAddToCart").className += " animated fadeInUp";
    document.getElementById("BTNAddToCart").style.visibility = "visible";
}

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of the filler text you could explain what `IsPostBack` is.

Comment: @Juhana [IsPostBack...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `0500` is 320, by the way.

Comment: @Xufox OK... How can I make sure it's working only on the first time the page load?

Comment: If you are running web forms then why don't inject `IsPostBack` value into javascript and check client side?

Comment: @nrodic And how do I do i it?

Comment: @harel486 you've only tagged this 'javascript' but it relies on other technologies that javascript-only people will be unaware of.  Please add  relevant tags (eg asp.net, asp.net-2.0 (?))

Comment: So you are in web forms. Then`<script>var isPostBack=<%= IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %></script>` will provide `isPostBack` variable in javascript. Use it as you wish, probably like `if (!isPostBack) { setTimeout(...) }`

Comment: @nrodic That works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Store a variable in Cookie at first page load and check the value of the variable every time.

Refer to [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/cookie-gettersetter/) for usage of Cookie.

**[UPDATED]**

I created a html for [demo](http://jsgao0.github.io/demo/page-load-status.html) and the [source](https://github.com/jsgao0/demo/blob/gh-pages/page-load-status.html) for you due to [**origin-same** policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) of Cookie.

I copied the source to as the following code for backup. You have to execute the following code on your own origin because **origin-same** policy as mentioned before.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pageLoadStatus"></div>
        <script>
            var _ = {};
            /**
             * Gets or sets cookies
             * @param name
             * @param value (null to delete or undefined to get)
             * @param options (domain, expire (in days))
             * @return value or true
             */
            _.cookie = function(name, value, options)
            {
                if (typeof value === "undefined") {
                    var n, v,
                        cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        n = $.trim(cookies[i].substr(0,cookies[i].indexOf("=")));
                        v = cookies[i].substr(cookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
                        if (n === name){
                            return unescape(v);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    options = options || {};
                    if (!value) {
                        value = "";
                        options.expires = -365;
                    } else {
                        value = escape(value);
                    }
                    if (options.expires) {
                        var d = new Date();
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() + options.expires);
                        value += "; expires=" + d.toUTCString();
                    }
                    if (options.domain) {
                        value += "; domain=" + options.domain;
                    }
                    if (options.path) {
                        value += "; path=" + options.path;
                    }
                    document.cookie = name + "=" + value;
                }
            };

            var hasLoadedBefore = _.cookie('hasLoadedBefore');
            if(!!hasLoadedBefore) $('#pageLoadStatus').text('This page has been loaded before.');
            else $('#pageLoadStatus').text('This page loaded at first time.');
            _.cookie('hasLoadedBefore', true);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see as the *demo*. You will see **This page loaded at first time.** at first page load and you'll also see **This page has been loaded before.** after you did reload the page. You can redisplay the demo by reseting Cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can't be 100% sure that your script will be runned only at the first loading.

If you really want to "secure" it, you can try to store data in session, cookies and localStorage.